# postMessage object from service worker to Angular component

Tags: angular, push-notification, service-worker, postmessage

How to pass this payload object to angular 4 component? I read about postMessage but It doesn`t work for me:( Can someone explain how to make it work okay?

Service worker:

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler((payload) => {
  const notificationOptions = {
    "body": data.body,
    "icon": "icon.png",
    "click_action": click_action
  };
  postMessage({'test'});
  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

Component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
     navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      console.log("Got reply from service worker: " + event.data);
   });
    self.addEventListener('message', event => { 
      console.log('MESSAGE: ',event.data); 
   });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one bug in your Service Worker code. You cannot *just* postMessage somewhere, you have to explicitly postMessage a spesific client. You have to first query the clients that are controlled by the Service Worker and then postMessage one of them. Check out the MDN documentation of [Client.postMesssage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage).

Also, in the component code you provided, you never register the Service Worker in the first place. You just add event listeners for messages sent through the postMessage API, but you don't initialize/register the Service Worker. I really suggest you to go through the [serviceworke.rs](https://serviceworke.rs/)'s excellent guides :-)

Answer (score -1):

### Update:

You can checkout demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-angular-sw-xlpuq?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

### ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Here is my working code snippet:

**Component:**

```
...
ngOnInit() {
  // Declair service worker variable in Angular Component
  const myServiceWorker = new Worker('path/to/sw.js');
  myServiceWorker.addEventListener('message', this.logWSPostMsg);
}

logWSPostMsg(message) {
  console.log('WS send to Component', message.data);
}
...
```

**Service Worker (sw.js)**

```
...
self.postMessage(msg); // It will send msg to Component
...
```

---

If you need send an object from SW to Component, you can call like this:

```
self.postMessage({key: "value"});
```

If you need postMessage from Component to SW, after declair service worker variable `myServiceWorker`, you can call:

```
myServiceWorker.postMessage(msg); // <msg> type any
```

and of course, sw.js need a listener:

```
self.onmessage = function (msg) {
  console.log('Component send to WS', msg.data);
}
```

Comment: `new Worker()` does not register a `ServiceWorker`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API#registration

Comment: That line is for declair SW variable inside Angular component, then use it to interactive with SW, check out my working sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-angular-sw-xlpuq?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Your working example loads a `WebWorker` which is completely different from `ServiceWorker`. I can also confirm this in your demo by running the following: `navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(console.dir)`.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will do some more research